# Matlab - Setting font size separately for x&y axes

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I am using the Property Editor in Matlab 2016a to customise my plot for publication. I would like to increase the font size of my x axis labels, while leaving those of the y axis unchanged. However, the FontSize property changes both at the same time, and I did not find any separate properties for the font on the two axes. Can this be done in Property Editor, or at least is there a command-line workaround?

Comment: C'mon, did you even try to do a search? The above duplicate I found within 30 seconds of searching on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlabel('x-axis','FontSize',18); %where label is x-axis, and fontsize is 18
```